# how to disable js2-mode syntax checking globally in spacemacs

Tags: emacs, js2-mode, spacemacs

Since im using eslint, syntax checking from js-mode is redundant to me. so how to turn it off globally instead of toggling on and off?

I configured eslint not to check for semicolons, but js2-mode still checks it. if js2-mode syntax checking cant be disabled globally, is there a way to only turn off semicolon check?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

shangsunset's answer only disables the semi-colon warning, to disable all js2-mode errors and warnings globally, you'll need something like this in your .spacemacs's `dotspacemacs/user-config` section:

```
;; Turn off js2 mode errors & warnings (we lean on eslint/standard)
(setq js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil)
(setq js2-mode-show-strict-warnings nil)
```

Comment: One could also just call `js2-toggle-warnings-and-errors` if you want it on the fly, which is bound to `, w`

Answer (score 15):

putting `(setq js2-strict-missing-semi-warning nil)` in .spacemacs solves my issue.

Comment: I think you'd better add a complete guide as `(setq js2-strict-missing-semi-warning nil)`~

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to toggle manually `SPC t s`. There's [documentation](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/syntax-checking#disabling-by-default) as to how to disable it in your .spacemacs file, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: where do you put the setting in your .spacemacs? did you try putting in user-init or user-config? i think im more focused on js2-mode than flycheck